# C - How can I take words from file without numbers, special characters(, . ? &)?

Tags: c, file, cpu-word, scanf

I want to take words from file.And I am send to array. I did this with fscanf. But, it is taking numbers, characters(, . % & # ! ?) and other things. How can I control this statement ?

```
int main(void) 
{       
  char path[100];
  printf("Please, enter path of file: "); scanf("%s",&path);
  FILE *dosya;
  char kelime[1000][50];
  int i=0;

  if((dosya = fopen(path,"r")) != NULL)
  {
    while(!feof (dosya))
    {
        fscanf(dosya,"%s",&kelime[i]);
        i++;
    }
  }
  else{printf("Not Found File !");}
  fclose(dosya);
}
```

Comment: Don't use `while (!feof(...))`, it will in most cases not work as expected. Instead use e.g. `while (fscanf(dosya, "%s", &kelime[i]) == 1)`.

Comment: As for your problem, you might find [this `scanf` (and family) reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) useful, especially the part about the `"%["` format.

Comment: BTW `fclose` should be inside the `if ... != NULL` check. Some (most?) systems will crash when closing a `NULL`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong

Comment: `Not Found File !` is what is known as a useless error message.  `if((dosya = fopen(path,"r")) == NULL ) { perror(path);}`

Comment: Why are you giving `scanf` the address of `path`? `scanf("%s",&path);`? `path` is already a pointer, so `path` is all you need. (may help some of those strange characters disappear as well...)

Answer (score 2):

Use `"%[]"` to distinguish between letters and non-letters.

```
#define NWORDS (1000)
char kelime[NWORDS][50];

size_t i;
for (i=0; i<NWORDS; i++) {
  // Toss ("*" indicates do not save) characters that are not ("^" indicates `not`) letters.
  // Ignore return value
  fscanf(dosya, "%*[^A-Za-z]");

  // Read letters
  // Expect only a return value of 1:Success or EOF:no more file to read
  // Be sure to limit number of characters read: 49
  if (fscanf(dosya, "%49[A-Za-z]", kelime[i]) != 1) break;
}

// do something with the `i` words
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `fgetc()`

```
char str[1000];
while((ch=fgetc(fname))!=EOF)
{
        // Write your code here;
        if((ch>='0' && ch<='9') || (ch<'a' && ch>'z') || (ch<'A' && ch>'Z'))
              continue;
        str[i++]=ch;
}
str[i]='\0';
```

When you use `fscanf()` the statement can't be parsed. So you have to

1. check it char by char
2. If not special characters or number then add to string

Comment: You fail to indicate how this helps the OP to exclude the characters that he is avoiding.

Comment: @DavidHoelzer is it okay now?